# Js file becomes non-functional as soon as I require ipcRenderer

Tags: electron, node.js-fs, ipcrenderer

I was testing the `ipcRenderer` process for my project and I got to a point where, in my javascript file, I require `ipcRenderer`:

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
```

In my HTML file, I have declared:

```html
 <script type="javascript" src="myjavascriptfile.js"></script>
```

As soon as I do this, any code, function or anything declared in my JS file just doesn't work without any errors in the console or any other notifications.

I already set `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: false` in my `main.js` that is the main file for Electron.

If however there is any other solution to the issue, my purpose is to get a textarea value and id of the line, send it to an object, and save it as a JSON file. I am using `ipcRenderer` to send the values to `ipcMai`n and there is `fs` from node to create the file. However as described above, I am not able to get this to work.

This is just the example as of how I am wanting to use, this is not the final code of course, but if I get this to work, I will process the other stuff:

```js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').remote

const Savebtn = document.getElementById("SaveSong")
let song = ['text', 'id']

Savebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('save', song)
  console.log(song)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, enabling `nodeIntegration` and/or disabling `contextIsolation` will create **security vulnerabilities** into your app. Don't do that unless you have good reasons and that you are sure of what you are doing. Next, the `remote` module has been deprecated since [Electron 12](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-12-0#removeddeprecated-changes), and removed since [Electron 14](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module), you should not (and don't need to) use it.

When everything is configured to be secure, you need to use a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file in order to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). For example:

**Main**

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false, // This is default
    contextIsolation: true, // This is default
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') // Path to your preload file
  }
});
```

**Preload**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer  } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  saveSong: (song) => ipcRenderer.send("save", song)
});
```

**Renderer**

```js
Savebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  window.electronAPI.saveSong(song);
});
```

Make sure you are not using `require` in your [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process) and that you only import into your preload what's available with [sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox) (otherwise you'll get more errors).

You can read more about security [in the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security), and find more working examples also [in the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I was able to get it to work by just requiring form require('electron').ipcRenderer but I believe using preload will be a better solution

Comment: @AshBabayan Yes, using a preload is better because of all the reasons I mentionned. The method you are using is not secure.

Comment: Agree. However my another problem with this would be that I anyways need nodeIntegrations as I need to have access to file system from node, and I need to get fs

Comment: @AshBabayan Have you read my answer? You don't need `nodeIntegration`, everything you need can be accessed with the bridge. Use `fs` on main and use IPC to communicate between processes. Please read the docs I linked, everything is explained with examples.